# How do I understand the Aussie English accent?

Tags: accent

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FH2UnMxR3IM&t=2m0s)
I am unable to understand commentary at [2:00](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FH2UnMxR3IM&t=2m0s) by an Australian and also at [1:54](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FH2UnMxR3IM&t=1m54s).What does he say?

Which method should I adopt to learn English effectively if I don't have native speakers to talk to.Any website available for learning with subtitles?

Comment: Every English language movie that has subtitles available to watch. You might want to try some Australian films. You can find lists online.

Comment: Where are subtitles?How to get them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see why you find this tricky, a few good reasons:

1. There's a lot of crowd noise, the recording is a little indistict
2. The Aussie accent uses different vowel sounds from those of other English variants and different emphasis. I'm not sure I can catch every word.
3. Technical jargon, even if you understand cricket you may not use all these terms.

1:54 He's knocked (or maybe got?) the game on its head. Fantastic.

I'm not completely clear as to the speaker's intent. If he is intending to say that the game has effectively been decided in England's favour, the outcome is now determined, then "knocked the game on its head" is fitting. Looking at the score, 48-2, while it's a major advantage for England I (and I assume Ian Botham) would not agree that there's no play left. Hence I'm wondering whether the intent is actually to say that the advantage has shifted from Australia to England and the game has been "turned on its head".

2:00 Big leg cutter, big outside edge and a fast nick

- leg cutter: ball deviates off the pitch towards the leg side
- outside edge: ball hit edge of bat
- fast nick: ball goes through to catcher very rapidly

Comment: "He's **knocked** the game on its head" is the usual BrE expression.

Comment: Yes, I've modified the answer; that is more likely than I first thought. However the speaker is Aussie, not a Brit, and I don't think the game has been knocked on its head - lots more work to do.

Comment: You are too god to understand these.I want to practice by understanding wit subtitles.Which videos/films are available with subtitles and where?

Answer (score -2):

I would use the Youtube close captions in that source. They can be activated by clicking on the button to the left of the cog. Here you will get subtitles to read.

Comment: Auto generated. Looks pretty useless to me. "What an over" is subtitles as "water now"

Comment: What @djna said. The vast majority of Youtube subtitles are very poor quality. For actual *movies*, [subscene](https://subscene.com/subtitles) is usually okay.

Comment: You do get volunteers doing it sometimes, so some videos will be accurate.